# Build NodeJS API before moving to production?

Tags: node.js

I'm new with NodeJS. I just built a NodeJS Rest API.

It was a very simple API, but the node_modules folder size is over 200mb. How can I build/compress the files before moving to production? Not sure if it's possible.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you care at all about the size of your node_modules file for a server?  Why would you want to complicate updating modules, debugging, etc... by messing with things?

Comment: Because I need to upload it to the server and it seems that will take a lot of time every time I need to upload something in my application

Comment: Well, there's no universal way to trim down a module to remove things that aren't needed in production so you'd have to study each module and figure it out separately for each module.  I'd personally be surprised if it was worth the trouble.  Perhaps you can make changes and do incremental uploads rather than reuploading the entire thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suppose you could do is to upload everything to the server *without* node_modules folder. Then, on the server, you can `cd` into the folder with your application and run `npm install`. This of course depends on you having run `npm init` before starting development and having a valid `package.json` file in your project root folder.

This approach is standard and here's why:

1. Downloading modules straight on the server from NPM is going to be faster than uploading them to the server.
2. You could've been developing on a platform different from your server. It is possible some modules might have platform-dependent components.
3. Some modules may require compiling small binaries upon installation. That should generally be done on target machine.